# BP search_term multiple fields

Tags: php, html, wordpress, search, buddypress

trying to search for members in my blog using multiple fields.

```
<?php if ( bp_has_members( "search_terms=Red Box" ) AND bp_has_members( "search_terms=Blue Box" ))  : ?>
<?php while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); ?>

…html here

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, if I use this code the result shows me just the 'Blue Box' Members and no both.

Any Advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the BuddyPress documentation:

> To search on multiple terms, put a space between each term. The search is based on ‘AND’, not ‘OR’. So only members who have selected / entered both ‘poodles’ and ‘carrots’ will be returned.

```
<?php if ( bp_has_members( 'search_terms=poodles carrots' ) ) : ?>
```

This apparently does not work if the search terms contain spaces.

See the documentation for [The Members Loop](https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/loops-reference/the-members-loop/), specifically the `my_custom_ids()` example. You can use a similar function to pass in query terms, run a SQL statement to only get members those terms apply to, then return a string that looks like `include=1,2,5,6,7` to fetch only those user IDs.

Comment: thank for that, I have seen the documentation however, when if I had %20 for the spaces there are no results.

Comment: I just dug through the code and your best bet is to write a custom function to return the user IDs, then pass that to `bp_has_members()`.

Comment: here is where I am having trouble because the del;action is done by option tags and using search_terms={$_POST['category']}